# Excel: Array to List (Combine time columns with date rows)

Tags: arrays, excel, list, date, time

In excel, I have a table with dates as rows and hours (0-24) as columns, and values at their intercept. 
I would like to change this array (365 by 24) to a list such that:
    Monday Hour1 value;
    Monday Hour2 value;
    Monday ...;
    Monday Hour24 value;
    Tuesday Hour1 value;
    Tuesday ... ;
    Tuesday Hour 24 value;
    ect

Is there anyway to do this in Excel? Without having to transpose rows 365 times.

Thank you for your help

Comment: There's usually a way.  Could you provide a better example of what you want your data to look like (and how it looks now)?

Comment: Now it is an array (date, time). I would like to make it a list with days in the first column, hours in the second, and values in the third. Since there are 24 hours per day, day identifiers will be repeated 24 times before moving to the next day.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data, with any code you have, and how you have the array set up?

Comment: Loop through array? Concat date to each element of time. Loop to next date.

Answer (score 0):

Use HLOOKUP to build a new list that finds hours in the original array that correspond to the level of the day.